# Date comparison is not happening in op:eq function in optical query

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-optic-api

I am trying to compare the dates in optical query but its not working as expected.
Below is my optical query

```
let $lastDay := '2021-01-31'
op:as("BalanceAmount", op:case((
        op:when(op:eq(op:view-col("Table1", "InvoiceDate"), $lastDay), ("Table1", "BalanceAmount"))),
        op:view-col("Table1", "InitialAmount")))
```

above query is not working as expected and when the InvoiceDate matches to $lastDay value, I am not getting correct value

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? Does the `op:when` condition never match and always use the alternative, or do you get any errors reported? Is your InvoiceDate column an `xs:date` or an `xs:string`? If it's a date, have you tried making sure that $lastDay is a date? i.e. `xs:date('2021-01-31')`

Comment: @Mads Hansen : I am not able to use some of the functions which is there in marklogic 10( i am using marklogic 10) like op:join-full-outer in my code. when i am using this function, i am getting undefined function error. How to resolve this

Comment: Is the module importing the optic.xqy library?  An example is here: https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/app-dev/OpticAPI#id_68685 ; also, note that expression functions require separate imports as documented here: https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/app-dev/OpticAPI#id_94816